# RGB normals not summing up rightly.

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, normals

So I generated a normal map for a sphere in Blender, and it looks pretty good. However, in order to be sure that the normals were right, I decided to sum up the RGB channels in MATLAB, and it turns out that the R, G, B values squared do not sum up to 1 (which is what you would expect).

Does anyone have any input?

Comment: Should they really sum up to 1? I don't know much about math so can't really answer but there may be many variables at play here, namely image encoding. What image format did you use. Does it have compression? Are color values even stored linearly?

Comment: I would expect them to sum up to one, assuming that the X, Y, and Z normal components are encoded as R, G, B values from 0 to 255.  I also made sure to renormalize by dividing by 255. I did not compress the image, and the image was stored in the .png format.

Answer (score 1):

They should have a magnitude of (approximately) 1. I say approximately as precision could be an issue.

You need to make sure that you are mapping the rgb values correctly back into decimal values, each colour range should map to the decimal range -1 to 1 with 128 mapping to 0.

You mention in comments that you renormalise by dividing by 255, this is incorrect. You should divide by 128 and subtract 1.

Note that the z / blue channel has its sign flipped compared to the others, but this shouldn't be an issue checking the magnitude. Also some software also flips other channels.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping#How_it_works